# jQuery active parent li on click child li

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add active class to  parent `li` after clicking on link in child `li`. I have drop down menu, on my drop down menu HTML code is in following website:
 http://www.dawntravels.com/

I've tried this code without success:

```
<script>
    $(".arrow_carrot-2right").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected'); // I also tried .parent().addClass
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please also post your html

Comment: `$(".arrow_carrot-2right")` always has `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`. When does it appear.

Comment: when the page is loaded there is a script error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: wrap your code within `$(document).ready(function(){ //cod goes here});`

Comment: @Ballbin i am unable to post html there but i mention my site link where that is menu

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="arrow_carrot-2right">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.arrow_carrot-2right > li').click(function () {    
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected{
    background-color:green;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bS75H/

Answer (score 0):

As  your class `arrow_carrot-2right` applied in `<i>` not on `anchor tag` so try this,

```
$('ul.sf-menu li a').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//get the current URL
var url = window.location;
//after the link has been clicked and page loaded,
//find the clicked anchor tag using the loaded page name
$('.sf-menu a').filter(function() {
   return this.href == url;
//add the 'active' class to the outermost parent <li> of the matched <a> tag
}).parents("li").addClass('active');
```